# Расположение блоков

Tags: html, css

В верстке двухколоночный макет
[image]

для левой колонки задано обтекание справа при помощи float: left, в блоке, где находятся посты блога

```
<article class="post">
                <h2 class="postTitle"> Оптимизация страниц сайта</h2>
                <p class="postInfo">Создана <time datetime="2011-06-14" class="postDate">14.06.2011</time>, Категория <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="postLink">Статьи</a>, by <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="postLink">babanovd</a></p>
                <div class="postImg">
                    <img src="images/image_2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
                <p class="postText">Любой сайт состоит из нескольких (десятков, сотен, тысяч) страниц. Любая страница — это некий HTML-код. HTML-код, в свою очередь, — это набор тегов, из которых и формируется страница.Оптимизация страниц — важнейший этап в продвижении сайта. Его можно разбить на следующие шаги.</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="postFullLink">Продолжить</a>
            </article> <!-- /article-->
```

для изображения так же задано float: left.
Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы последующий пост не наползал на предыдущий, если в посте мало текста, как это получается [здесь](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index.html).
Если задать после p class="postText" `<div class="clear"></div>` то возникает разрыв [link text](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index3.html).
Как можно добиться нужного расположения элементов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть два варианта:

1. для article.post - задать **overflow: hidden;**
2. создать псевдоэлемент -

   **article.post:after {
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      display: block;
      clear: both;
   }**

Вроде как-то так, если не напутал со стилями. Погуглите, тема раздутая...

Если не поможет, и до вечера не справитесь, то помогу.

Удачи

**UPD:** Вот, ловите пример - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/T2Pj2/2/

Comment: Спасибо, у меня сделано по первому варианту, с overflow: hidden. Второй вариант, к сожалению, не кроссбраузерный, псевдоэлемент after не сработает в ие8 и ие7. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Heidel, Второй вариант с псевдо-элементами, так же можно сделать кроссбраузерными, вот здесь почитайте на досуге, если интересно: http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/glyuki-brauzerov/IE/after-before-for-ie.html

Comment: Кроме того, первый вариант удобен только в тех случаях, когда есть уверенность, что размер топика будет фиксированный и не будет увеличено количество символов, иначе, все, что не влезет  в размер, обрежется. Так, что будьте аккуратны.

Comment: Почему? у меня же не задана высота блока .post и всё срабатывает. Если я увеличиваю количество текста в блоке .postText, длина блока просто увеличивается вниз, ничего не обрезается.  
За ссылки на то как сделать псевдоэлемент after кроссбраузерным спасибо, почитаю!

Comment: А..., ну если так, тогда я спокоен :) 

Удачи!

P.S. За спасибо, - пожалуйста!